# Wordpress Forward Slash

Tags: wordpress

I'm creating a website with WordPress that is for a group of people to use to communicate. The plugin i'm using to list the users is 'WP User Manager' and when it lists the users it lists as 'www.mywebsite.com/profile/22'.  However, when I click on it, it just re-directs to 'www.mywebsite.com/profile/'.  And when I try 'www.mywebsite.com/profile/22/' it goes to the right page, but the plugin does not have an option to change it to add the '/' at the end.  Has anyone found out how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the default WordPress .htaccess file.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

You can add a trailing slash by adding the following below the WordPress portion of the .htaccess file.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```